# Unable to add git subtree

Tags: flutter, gitlab, git-subtree

I am trying to establish a git subtree in my project and for some reason I keep getting a message saying `You must provide the --prefix option.` I am making a Flutter project and the project repo (as well as sub repo) are both on gitlab.

Below is the command that I am running in the console while in my root project directory.

```
git subtree add —-prefix=subtrees/mysubtree https://git.company.com/subdirectory/subtree_repo.git master — squash
```

I have experimented a little with the command. For instance I tried `—-prefix subtrees/mysubtree` (sans `=`), as well as `git config alias.sba 'subtree add --prefix subtrees/mysubtree / https://git.company.com/subdirectory/subtree_repo.git master —-squash'`.

The last command doesn't throw any errors and it actually triggers `pub get` but no files change and no directories are added (at least not to the root which is where I am running the command).

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong and the messages (when there are messages) aren't very informative. I have checked my syntax and referenced it with [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/subtree.html) as well as with [this](https://www.netways.de/en/blog/2016/01/14/working-with-git-subtree/#:%7E:text=Purge%20a%20subtree,unlike%20known%20from%20git%20submodules.) post.